# Replace value (regex) in text file with nothing by using python

Tags: python, replace, text-files

**MODIFIED:**

I'm trying with python, read the file, find a specific section, remove it

The line (which appears in the documents several times with different variables) to be replaced with NOTHING:

```
, "total": VARIABLE, "stats": {VARIABLE}, "took": VARIABLE
```

I understand the principal how to replace one text to another:

```
.replace('XXX', 'YYY')\
```

Will try to find all XXX and will replace with YYY

**Apply this technology to my issue:**

```
.replace(', "total": VARIABLE, "stats": {VARIABLE}, "took": VARIABLE', '')\
```

This method is working (theoretically) the only part which I do not understand, with what needs to replace **VARIABLE** so it will pick up anything is it **[a-zA-Z][0-9]**??  I'm a bit lost here

**EDIT 1.0:**

Based on extra research , need to use "import re" - RegEx

```
regExData = re.sub(r', "total":(.*) , "stats": {(.*)}, "took":(.*)', '', LFPostData)
```

But not sure how to use it exactly.

Comment: This smells like an XY question... **Why** do you want to replace it with nothing? What you did is alright in order to remove the line, but it seems like it's a bad approach to solving a bigger task.

Comment: Looks like a JSON file....

Comment: @YotamSalmon this part is just in the middle of the line which breaks consistency, and I need to remove it to make it work this is just a small issue (not part of the big problem)

Comment: @Rakesh this is modified JSON file, so all JSON ways of modifing it, will not work... that's why it is just text file issue

Comment: What consistency standard does it break? Maybe an example for what that line could be and what the file you're trying to process is?

Comment: @YotamSalmon Big Query upload consistency breaks, as BQ need the file formatted in the certain way (it is not simple JSON), and data with which I'm currently working is ***** .. so have to reformat it completely, this small thing is the last part for this section.

Comment: Do you mind giving us a better example and the output you are expecting for it? It's pretty unclear as it stands.

Comment: @Austin in simple term explanation is: I need to remove this line from the file (this line is in the middle) completely, where it says (ANYTHING), this is variable the value could be changed so need to use something like this - [a-zA-Z1-9]*

Comment: @Austin have update question, made it more clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the matches of a `RegEx` pattern you define, then replace each of this string in your text:

```
import re

raw_text = r'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut, "total": VARIABLE, "stats": {VARIABLE}, "took": VARIABLE labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea, "total": bobi, "stats": {42}, "took": vori commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. '

matches = re.findall(r', "total": \S*, "stats": {\S*}, "took": \S*', raw_text)



for match in matches:
    raw_text = raw_text.replace(match, ' ')

print(raw_text)
```

OUTPUT:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod
>   tempor incidunt ut  labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
>   veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit
>   laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea  commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Notice that we have 2 occurence of your pattern `, "total": VARIABLE, "stats": {VARIABLE}, "took": VARIABLE`, with different values.
The RegEx `, "total": \S*, "stats": {\S*}, "took": \S*` is pretty simple:

`, "total":` is a literal match
`\S*` matches anything that isn't a space
`, "stats": {` is a literal match
`\S*` matches anything that isn't a space
`}, "took":` is a literal match
`\S*` matches anything that isn't a space

with `re.findall` you find all the occurence of the given pattern. This means that `print(matches)` will output:

> [', "total": VARIABLE, "stats": {VARIABLE}, "took": VARIABLE', ',
>   "total": bobi, "stats": {42}, "took": vori']

Which is the list of all the matches.

Then we `.replace` each of the matches in our raw_text

This should answer all your doubts, but you should probably re-consider your general approach, as I also think (as suggested in some comments) that you're mistreating a JSON

Answer (score 0):

1) I use python "replace", to remove {} as they cause an issue in sub (regExpression)

```
.replace(' "stats": {}, ', '')
```

2) Then I use (import re) -Python RegEx to remove the rest

```
regExData = re.sub(r', "total": ([a-zA-Z0-9]+),"took": ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', '', LFPostData)
```

Comment: @Austin If someone has the better answer, will appreciate and will mark it as accepted answer.